# Python Django, производительность вывода

Tags: django, оптимизация, pagination

Подскажите, кто очень хорошо разбирается в Django
Есть код выводящий с пагинатором темы. Или не важно какие именно данные

```
def themes_main(request):
    themes = Theme.objects.prefetch_related('user').all()
    paginator = Paginator(themes, 20)
    if 'page' in request.GET:
        page_num = request.GET['page']
    else:
        page_num = 1
    page = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    context = {'themes': page.object_list, 'page': page}
    return render(request, 'themes/themes_main.html', context)
```

Вопрос следующий:
Допустим у меня огромная посещаемость, и огромное количество тем в бд
Судя по первой строке в теле функции, берутся все темы, просто во вьюхе разбиваются пагинатором
При том что там могут быть тысячи страниц тем, и сотни тысяч пользователей онлайн, это значит что пользователям придётся очень очень долго ждать загрузки?
Как оптимизировать подобное?

Answer (score 2):

Как можете видеть в коде ниже, пагинатор работает в 2 запроса. Первый считает общее кол-во, а второй делает выборку через LIMIT. Если добавите индексы, то все должно работать быстро. Так же можете включить кеширование запросов, что ускорит работу при одинаковых запросах.

```
class Paginator(object):

    def __init__(self, object_list, per_page, orphans=0,
                 allow_empty_first_page=True):
        self.object_list = object_list
        self._check_object_list_is_ordered()
        self.per_page = int(per_page)
        self.orphans = int(orphans)
        self.allow_empty_first_page = allow_empty_first_page

    def validate_number(self, number):
        """
        Validates the given 1-based page number.
        """
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise PageNotAnInteger(_('That page number is not an integer'))
        if number < 1:
            raise EmptyPage(_('That page number is less than 1'))
        if number > self.num_pages:
            if number == 1 and self.allow_empty_first_page:
                pass
            else:
                raise EmptyPage(_('That page contains no results'))
        return number

    def page(self, number):
        """
        Returns a Page object for the given 1-based page number.
        """
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        bottom = (number - 1) * self.per_page
        top = bottom + self.per_page
        if top + self.orphans >= self.count:
            top = self.count
        return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)

    def _get_page(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns an instance of a single page.

        This hook can be used by subclasses to use an alternative to the
        standard :cls:`Page` object.
        """
        return Page(*args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        """
        Returns the total number of objects, across all pages.
        """
        try:
            return self.object_list.count()
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            # AttributeError if object_list has no count() method.
            # TypeError if object_list.count() requires arguments
            # (i.e. is of type list).
            return len(self.object_list)

    @cached_property
    def num_pages(self):
        """
        Returns the total number of pages.
        """
        if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
            return 0
        hits = max(1, self.count - self.orphans)
        return int(ceil(hits / float(self.per_page)))

    @property
    def page_range(self):
        """
        Returns a 1-based range of pages for iterating through within
        a template for loop.
        """
        return six.moves.range(1, self.num_pages + 1)

    def _check_object_list_is_ordered(self):
        """
        Warn if self.object_list is unordered (typically a QuerySet).
        """
        ordered = getattr(self.object_list, 'ordered', None)
        if ordered is not None and not ordered:
            obj_list_repr = (
                '{} {}'.format(self.object_list.model, self.object_list.__class__.__name__)
                if hasattr(self.object_list, 'model')
                else '{!r}'.format(self.object_list)
            )
            warnings.warn(
                'Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered '
                'object_list: {}.'.format(obj_list_repr),
                UnorderedObjectListWarning,
                stacklevel=3
            )
```